# Report Server Configuration Manager - User does not have the necessary rights to read recognizer information

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver, ssrs-2019

I am trying to configure a URL to access the web portal for Report Server 2019. I click apply with the default settings after configuring everything else and get this error.

*The application is not found. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: TabletPC inking error code. User does not have the necessary rights to read recognizer information (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040236)*

The log states that ReportingServicesWebApp is not configured.

*023-09-18 10:20:14.5267|INFO|1|ReportingServiesWebApp is not configured - not listening on any URLs*

*2023-09-18 10:20:14.5267|INFO|1|Ensure the database instance hosting the catalog is running, and URLs are configured via RSConfig tool.*

This is an upgrade from SSRS 2012 that I've followed all the steps from the documentation Microsoft has for migrating versions.

I tried a virtual account service and a network account service and neither have worked. I am wondering if this is a permission issue or a configuration issue.

[image: Screenshot of Report Server Configuration Manager]

Comment: There is a link (supposedly) telling you what's wrong and how to fix in your screenshot, looks like there was an existing virtual directory that could not be recreated. You could try using a different folder name first, that would at least point you at the existing folder being the problem.

Comment: The link is the Exception Details window shown above it. I tried a different folder name before with no luck unfortunately.